# Ruby on Rails for a GameBattles type site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My question is pretty much as the title says. Its Ruby on Rails a good framework to create a website like http://gamebattles.majorleaguegaming.com/ or http://www.umggaming.com/. I want to at the end of the day make a website where people can make an account log on and find tournaments to play on where the site will have scheduled tournaments and keep track of win/loss stats ect. But I'm not sure what framework I should use or anything like that. I've been looking at everything. But everything I read says Ruby on Rails is good for beginners and it can be used frontend and backend.

I'm really new to website developing and programming in general. I've only dived into HTML, and CSS, and very very little Javascript.

Comment: any web framework will do. ruby on rails is also good for this

Comment: I'd say Rails is an excellent way to start. Ruby is a language that's pretty easy to pick up. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I've been looking up a lot of ruby on rails stuff and it says I should Learn PHP whats your opinions?